# Images thumbnail not cropping square

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a related post file with **squares** images.

In the `functions.php` I've added the following code:

```
function my_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    
    // Add Image Sizes  
    add_image_size( 'related-posts', 200, 200, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup' );
```

In my `related-posts.php`, I've added the code:

```
<?php 
$recent_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3, // Number of posts to display
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
);      

$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $recent_args );
 
if ( $recent_posts ->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul class="list-unstyled d-flex text-center">';
    while ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="border col-md-4 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                <div class="relatedthumb">
                    <a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() )?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <div class="related-post-thumb">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('related-posts'); ?>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="relatedcontent">
                    <h3>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>        
            </li>
    <?php } 
    echo '</ul>';

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

For example, I have an original image: 1600 x 1067 pixels. But the hard cropping is not working. The image has the size 200 x 133 px but not 200 x 200 as I expected.
To check if the problem is my code I've tried different things like:

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
```

But I got a 150x100px image size.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
```

But I got a 300x200px image size.
I also tried to regerate thumbnails via plugins, but nothing works.
The */wp-admin > Settings > Media* method seems to have no effect on my thumbnails.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/#reserved-image-size-names) on the `add_image_size()` function, "related-posts" is not a valid input for the first parameter (unless you've defined it elsewhere). I believe "custom-size" is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @YourManDan, but what would be the valid input in this case? `add_image_size( 'custom-size', 200, 200, true );` ?

Comment: Actually, I think I may have been hasty in commenting, my apologies. Looking it over once more it does follow the documentation. I'll leave it to someone more experience to help you out :)

Comment: how are you checking the image dimensions? Are you inspecting the `<img>` tags dimensions, or the actual image itself when visited directly? It could be that no resizing is taking place, or that the code is set to show the full sized image and CSS is scaling it down to fit the container

Comment: @YourManDan no problem!

Comment: @TomJNowell I've updated the post with a print to explain.

Comment: yup, its intrinsic size is not 200x200, it's using the _full_ image size, and the browser is scaling it down to fit. Think of it like showing an image that's 5 meters wide on your phone, your phone isn't 5 meters wide, that doesn't mean the image is now 5 inches wide. Rendered size != intrinsic size. It's a 1600px image being displayed at 200px, when what you need is a 200px widget resized image. This can happen when your server fails to create the intermediate image sizes, either due to PHP errors or lack of resources

Comment: also that looks like an unsplash image, are you using the unsplash plugin or a CDN plugin?

Comment: @TomJNowell Hm.. I got it. Thanks! I'm not using the unsplash plugin, I downloaded the image and uploaded at the post. But in this case, do you think is there something I can do to have the thumbnail cropped or the only solution is to use css?

Comment: does this problem go away if you upload a file with a smaller resolution, e.g. 512x512px? And can you confirm that there is nothing in the PHP error log about images, and that the resized versions of that file exist on the server by directly checking the folder in an FTP client? There should be a number of JPEG files alongside the image in your screenshot with image sizes and dimensions appended to their filenames

Comment: @TomJNowell I have no idea how to figure this out. It is already beyond my knowledge. All I can say is that an image 512x341px uploaded get a width="200" and height="150". An image 512x512px get the 200x200px as I need, but I have to upload a square image to have a square thumbnail  in the related posts. `Rendered size: 200 × 200 px
Rendered aspect ratio: 1∶1
Intrinsic size: 512 × 512 px
Intrinsic aspect ratio: 1∶1`

and
`Rendered size: 200 × 150 px
Rendered aspect ratio: 4∶3
Intrinsic size: 512 × 384 px
Intrinsic aspect ratio: 4∶3`

Comment: if it works ok then you will see your image size mentioned in the filename, but what you've shown me does not. Likewise the intrinsic size of the image would be 200px but it is not. You need to confirm that the image sizes are indeed being created, by going into the folder aka `wp-content/uploads/2023/etc..` and looking at the files in that folder, to confirm if they exist, or if it's just the original file you uploaded

Comment: for example, if I upload `test.png`, and look in the folder, I see `test.png`, but I also see `test-150x150.png` etc, every image size be that `medium` or `thumbnail` has a file and they're all there side by side. Since your image size is 200 by 200 I would expect to see a file with the same image but `-200x200` added to the filename. Note that this information is super critical to solving your problem, without confirmation it may be impossible to solve your problem. Since you're using a local dev environment, you can look it up in your editor app or windows explorer/Finder.

Comment: have you confirmed this still doesn't work when you turn off all plugins? And did you look at your PHP error log?

Comment: @TomJNowell I looked at the folder 'uploads' but as you said, there is no images like `myimage-150x150.png`. Only the original file uploaded. I'm trying to find out where is the PHP error log.

Comment: Finally worked @TomJNowell. As you said, the problem was my xampp. I found the solution (`the extension=gd` in `php.ini`). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was not in my code, but in the xampp! The GD extension was missing

Comment: for future reference this should show up in site health in WP Admin